# Printing scheduled posts in Hootsuite

Tags: hootsuite

We regularly schedule posts for Facebook and Twitter through the use of Hootsuite. One of our employees likes looking through the posts and highlighting things that need to be changed ... through actually printing it off and using a highlighter to point out changes.

Our problem is that (I think) the scroll bar on the page is limiting the print to only what the scroll bar is showing at that time. This might be because we `Right Click > Print` from Google Chrome to print the whole page. Either way, it is only printing a fraction of all of our posts. I know I can copy/paste into Word and print like that but I'm wondering if anyone has found an easier way to do this.

** Clarification: we want **all** of our posts to print, not just the ones that are visible.